Cardinalities for ternary relations in ERD diagram

Re that ERD:
I can represent a many-to-many relationship with m to m.
What is m to n in the ternary relationship?
Can I use it in a binary or unary relationship?
What does it mean?
What is m to k?
Can I use it in a binary or unary relationship?

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? An ERD is an image of DDL--text. (You could also give a diagram, but it's likely redundant.) Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Basic quesitons are faqs. Put all but only what you need to ask your 1 question into your post.

What method are you following, from what competent reference, what does it say to do & how are you 1st stuck?

Explanation of ER model to functional dependencies solution Mapping a ternary relationship to the relational model (Employes, Customer, Project) https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+Cardinalities+for+ternary+relations+in+ERD+diagram

The cardinality in ERD represent the maximum  of possible relations.  It can be 1, or it can be many.  Many is usually represented by a letter. You could use any letter in unary, binary, ternary and n-ary relationships, although M, N, P are the most frequent choices.
Most people use 1:N for one-to-many and M:N for many-to-many, and M:N:P for ternary many-to-many-to-many relations, because these were all used since the foundational academic paper of Peter Chen who has invented this notation (The two first articles of Chen use P in an example with a M:N:P ternary relationship).
Theoretically it can be any non numeric symbol although everybody sticks to letters. It's purposely a different letter for each link of a binary, ternary or n-ary relationship, to avoid giving the impression that several sides would always have the same cardinality.
When more than two are used, the usual sequence to pick from is M, N, P, R ... or N, M, K, J ... depending on personal preferences.  Again, it's just a common practice, so instead of M:N:P or M:N:K you could as well use X,Y,Z , although it could surprise some readers.
Note that the letters O, I, and to a lesser extent Q and L (if lowercase cardinalities letters are used) are usually avoided to prevent potential confusion with 0 and 1.

1-first the many to many relationships is denoted by m to n ,not m to m because the two sets are not equal. Binary relationship is relationship between 2 entities while unary relationship is within one entity.
2- yes, you can use them in binary or unary relationships m,k are cardinary notations,(1 patient has k nurses and 1 nurse have m patients)

Sorry , did not get it

There are alot of many to many relation ships that are represented using  M:M not M:N

why did I use K and N not M sympol
